# Field with Top Ranking Field Name

Tags: rank, hadoop, hive, hiveql

Let's imagine a table structured like this:

| Bucket | Red | Blue | Green |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| Second | 6 | 5 | 2 |

What I'm trying to achieve is based on the values within each bucket, I'd like to generate another set of fields with the highest ranking, second highest ranking, and third highest ranking colors (assume there are more than three colors as well). We are limiting to top 3.

Essentially, what my final output should look like is this:

| Bucket | Red | Blue | Green | Rank 1 | Rank 2 | Rank 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | 3 | 4 | Green | Blue | Red |
| Second | 6 | 5 | 2 | Red | Blue | Green |

Hoping this isn't a redundant question.

Comment: What did you try yourself? Why didn't it work?

Comment: @Colin'tHart I tried manually making a long case statement: which works for the top rank but couldn't figure out how to solve for intermediate ranks.

Comment: I made a solution, but with 2 disclaimers, so is more a suggestion to think about than a solution: 1) I know Postgres, I don't know Hiveql, and I use the [nth_value()](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-nth_value-function/) function, I've seen there is a [way to simulate it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675821/find-the-nth-value-in-hive); 2) I think that with a normalized table would be a lot simpler to solve this problem sistematically. So here is my example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=752428a9e15d0527cef963e69041649b